# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' for login page

Tags: php, syntax-error, parse-error

I'm getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' on line 8.

```
<?php

    $userid=$_POST['userid'];
    $pswd=$_POST['pswd'];

    if ($userid==("admin") & $pswd==("123"))
    (
    $_SESSION['userid'] = $userid;
    $_SESSION['pswd'] = $pswd;
    header("location:admin.php");
    )

    else echo 'Ops! Please try again.';

    ?>
```

here's line 8

```
$_SESSION['userid'] = $userid;
```

sorry, I know this can be just minor error, but I'm getting blind. thank you for helping!

Comment: Your `if` statement's body is wrapped in parentheses instead of curly braces.

Comment: how silly of me, thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not correct use this:

```
$userid = $_POST['userid'];
$pswd = $_POST['pswd'];

if($userid == "admin" && $pswd == "123")
{
  $_SESSION['userid'] = $userid;
  $_SESSION['pswd'] = $pswd;
  header("Location: admin.php");
} else {
   echo 'Ops! Please try again.';
}
```

Comment: *sidenote:* Correct syntax of `header()` should be: `header('Location: admin.php');` (note the capital letter & space) followed by `exit()`;

Answer (score 1):

You need change your if (you are opening and closing with **()** and you need do it with **{}** )

```
if ($userid==("admin") && $pswd==("123"))
{
$_SESSION['userid'] = $userid;
$_SESSION['pswd'] = $pswd;
header("location:admin.php");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors on your `if` statement. You forgot a `&` and you must write instructions into `{ }`.

It actually is

```
if ($userid=='admin' && $pswd=='123')
{
    //Instructions
}
```

Comment: the `(` and `)` are unnecessary. Also, use single quote instead of double quote to speed up parsing if possible.

Comment: I didn't really know about the quotes. Thank you :)